# PostgreSQL: Multiple stored procedures in one transaction

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, transactions

is it possible to call multiple stored procedures in one transaction and COMMIT/ROLLBACK all operations from all stored procedures?

For example:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
  CALL proc1();
  CALL proc2();
  CALL proc3();

  COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Yes. Make sure there is no `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` in the procedure bodies.